# How to send multiple (including root CA) certificates from .net client

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, certificate, client-certificates

We have been trying to solve an issue for a while.

We consume a web service with client certificates.

Service owners gave us a .p12 file, it contains the client certificate and CA and private key.

We can see the certification path from the certificate itself.

The issue is, when we try to call the web service via SOAP UI, it works. In SOAPUI we chose the .p12 file as keystore and set the password. It works.

[image]

When we try to call the web service via our .net client application, it does not work.

--this is how we call the web service

```
        channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<AcquisitionAutorisationService>(binding, serviceAddress);
        channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2();
        channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate.Import(@"C:\cert\abc.p12", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);
```

When we monitor the packages with WireShark, we saw that, SOAPUI sends two certificates both client certificate and certificate authority in the request.

[image]

But .Net client sends only the client certificate not CA. So firewall of the server does not allow our calls.

[image]

So my question is how come we managed to send the CA root with our request like SOAP UI, in .Net?

If anyone can give any idea about the issue, I would be appreciated!

Comment: Still no answer? Have you found a solution? I'm having a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

If the first client (SOAP UI) is sending the CA certificate, then it must be an intermediate CA certificate that is itself signed by another CA. A client would not have any reason to send a root CA certificate.

It could be as simple as installing the intermediate CA certificate on the server so that the second client need not send it.

It could also be as simple as installing the intermediate CA certificate on the client in the Windows certificate store for the local machine (or user), so that it is available when the client certificate chain is built.

Otherwise, I am pretty sure what you are looking for is how to get .NET to send the *intermediate* CA certificate in the client certificate chain.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Intermediate CA certificate is actually installed on client windows certificate store. But what I wonder, what creates the difference between SOAPUI and .net client? Because both applications uses the same .p12 file. (Sorry I am not an expert on those certification issues, I might be expressing the problem incorrectly)

Comment: I don't know the difference between those two particular clients, but for example, if you were to write an openssl-based client, depending on what API calls you make, openssl will or will not add the intermediate certificate to the chain. It all depends on the API, and then, what calls you make to that API.